# How to get data from xlsx sheet using dataprovider in selenium TestNG?

Tags: selenium, testng

Can someone give me the logic of how to retrieve data from an Excel sheet (latest Excel file format) using the data provider in Selenium?

I'm mostly looking for the for loop logic inside the data provider.

Comment: what have u tried till now?

Answer (score 0):

Bascially, `TestNG Data Provider` is anything you create.
If you want to read xlsx files you need to create a class which reads excel rows and returns dataset.

```
@DataProvider(name = "data")
    public static Object[][] returnExcelSheetData()
        throws BiffException, IOException 
        {
    String absolutePath = filePath.concat("/").concat(fileName); //path to excel file
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(absolutePath));
    Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
    Sheet worksheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName); //sheet name

    int ROWS = worksheet.getRows() - 1; //if headers are present - use -1
    int COLS = worksheet.getColumns(); //read all columns

    Object[][] dataset = new Object[ROWS][COLS];
    for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < ROWS; rowCount++) {
        for (int colCount = 0; colCount < COLS; colCount++) {
            dataset[rowCount][colCount] = worksheet.getCell(colCount,
                    rowCount + 1).getContents();
        }
    }
    workbook.close();
    file.close();
    return dataset;
```

for loops interate through ALL columns and ALL rows and return data sets.

If you use only 1 row of data and 1 row of headers, DataProvider will pass data to test.

If you use 2 rows of data, method which invokes `DataProvider` will be invoked for each row (2 times for 2 rows of data)

Comment: what will be code if i am using POI jar files,can you do modification?

Comment: can you give the complete code of how to get the data from excel sheet(.xlsx) using data provider and also using POI jar

Comment: I am not familiar with POI jar so I can't help you. 

The above is the working example of `@DataProvider`. This is complete code. You just need to add data Provider to your `@Test` class

Comment: You can either use `JUnit` or `TestNG`. Personally, I use `TestNG`, because it's more versitale.